# How can I check if a resource was created by CloudFormation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have inherited an AWS account with a lot of resources. Some of them were created manually, other by CloudFormation.

**How can I check if a resource (in my case Security Group) was created by CloudFormation and belongs to a stack?**

For some security groups `aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids real_id`  results in:

```
...
"Tags": [
            {
                "Value": "REAL_NAME",
                "Key": "aws:cloudformation:logical-id"
            },
            {
                "Value": "arn:aws:cloudformation:<REAL_ID>",
                "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-id"
            },
]
...
```

Other security groups don't have any tags.

Is it the only indicator? I mean, someone could easily remove tags form an SG created by CloudFormation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-resource-tags.html), in addition to any tags you define, AWS CloudFormation automatically creates the following stack-level tags with the prefix aws::

aws:cloudformation:*logical-id*

aws:cloudformation:*stack-id*

aws:cloudformation:*stack-name*

All stack-level tags, including automatically created tags, are propagated to resources that AWS CloudFormation supports. **Currently, tags are not propagated to Amazon EBS volumes that are created from block device mappings**.

--

This should be a good place to start with but since CF doesn't enforce the stack state so if someone deleted something manually then you would never know.

If I were you, I would export everything (supported) via Cloudformer and re-design the whole setup my way.

Another way:

You can pass *PhysicalResourceId* of a resource to *describe_stack_resources* and get the stack information if it belongs to a CF stack. This is an example:

`cf = boto3.client('cloudformation')
 cf.describe_stack_resources(PhysicalResourceId="i-0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")`

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Client.describe_stack_resources

Comment: So if there are no tags it's not possible to find out if a resource is managed by CF?

Comment: the cloudformation tags are not created for CMK too

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  After no luck finding an answer I made a quick PowerShell script that will just look for a resource name in all of the stacks.
When CF was introduced the stacks didn't tag resources and even now I have issues with CloudFormation reliably tagging resources, there are still times it will tag one resource and not tag another even with the same resource type and in the same stack.  In addition some resources like CloudWatch Alarms don't have tags.

```
$resourceName = "*MyResource*" #Part of the resource name, surrounded by asterisks (*)
$awsProfile = "Dev" #AWS Profile to use
$awsRegion = "us-east-1" #Region to query
Get-CFNStack -ProfileName $awsProfile -Region $awsRegion | Get-CFNStackResourceList -ProfileName $awsProfile -Region $awsRegion | Where-Object {$_.PhysicalResourceId -ilike $resourceName} | Select-Object StackName,PhysicalResourceId
```